# What's the advantage of using the lock-on shot in Deathsmiles?

Tags: deathsmiles

I've been playing Deathsmiles for some time now, and I still can't seem to figure out the usefulness of the lock-on shot.  I find it slow and difficult to use effectively and never use it, yet I see pro replays using it all the time.

When is it best to use the lock-on shot?  Are any bosses more susceptible to it than others?  Do any enemies drop more items as a result of being killed by it?

Basically, why should I ever use the lock-on shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i havent actually played the game you are referring to but here is a link to a website that should help, it discusses the effectiveness of each shot and gives some stats:

http://www.cave-stg.com/forum/index.php?topic=281.0